# What is the 'CL' stat in WFRP1e?

Tags: wfrp-1e

Curious as to what the '**Cl**' stat is listed on the character sheets, seems to be gone from 2nd and 3rd edition. I searched on the 'nets but have been unable to find any solid info on stats for 1st edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cool**

When converting characters to 2nd edition (2e), 2e *Will Power* is computed as the average of *Will Power (WP)* and *Cool (Cl)* from 1st edition (1e) characters.

Comment: Cool...ok, I knew I was going to facepalm when I got an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @OldWorlder You're welcome. I had to think about it for a couple of minutes and look for an image of the 1e character sheet to get context. I had one online from the release of 2e and was able to look at it to jog my memory.

Answer (score 4):

It's Cool. Which was used in both WFB1-3 and WFRP1 for the morale checks.

In fact, here's the whole list:
**M** Move 
**WS** Weapon Skill
**BS** Ballistic Skill, but often referred to as Bow Skill
**S** Strength
**T** Toughness
**W** Wounds
**I** Initiative. Also used for perception and dodges
**A** Attacks
**Dex** Dexterity
**Int** Intelligence
**Ld** Leadership (Mostly ability to command troops and get others to recover from failed cool tests)
**Cl** Cool (resistance to breaking from fear, horror, etc)
**WP** Willpower (Ability to recover from failed cool tests)
**Fel** Fellowship

WS, BS, S, T, W: all were 1-10 in both WFB and WFRP1 
I, Dex, Int, Ld, Cl, WP, and Fel: 2-12 in WFB (tho later 2-10 with bonuses up to +3), percentile in WFRP1

Comment: aramis is correct, in 1e many characteristics had direct corollaries in WFB, intended to allow character (RP) to hero (FB) play, and visa versa. Though I'm unsure that was actually done in broad practice at gaming tables. YMMV.

Comment: I switched to WFB 3 when big battles hit. So did many of my friends. But we used counters and half-scale.